# how to load a layout in background?

Tags: android, xml, splash-screen

I have a layout in my app that has lots of images, buttons and other layout elements.
The first time the user starts the activity of that layout, it causes the app to freeze for 1 second.
I want to load the heavy layout elements in my splash screen, so that when the user starts that for the first time there is no freezing.

How could I go about adding this feature into my app?

Comment: Please post some code

Answer (score 2):

First load all the UI elements and then try to load the images in your respective layout.

Loading the images can be long process, so use async task for that.

For loading the images efficiently you can use the following code shared by Google. Below is the link for that...

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look into AsyncTask Handler. It will also allow you to easily support progressbar.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you have a lot of images to load, you can use image loading libraries refer this link for more **[Image Loading Library](http://java.dzone.com/articles/be-lazy-productive-android-0).** These libraries load images in background and provides many more options to deal with images.